# How to do exception handling in Azure easy table?

Tags: azure, exception, azure-mobile-services

I have an iOS Mobile App and as a backend data source, I am using the easy table. insert/update script code is written in js files.

But if anything break in my backend code there is no way mobile app knows about it. how to implement exception handling so that I can send the exception to the mobile app?

```
 var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

 var insertMiddleware = function(req,res,next) {
 const util = require('util');
 var bPromiseRejected = false;
 var promises = [], promisesInsert = [], promisesUpdate = [];


var requestItem = req.body;
var tableRecord = req.azureMobile.tables('Table1');
var itemsToInsert = requestItem.ItemsToInsert;
var itemsToUpdate = requestItem.itemsToUpdate;


console.log('Step 1.' );

//delete records array from feature dict
delete requestItem["ItemsToInsert"];
delete requestItem["itemsToUpdate"];
//context.item = requestItem;

if (itemsToInsert) {
     promisesInsert = itemsToInsert.map(function(item) {

        return tableRecord.insert(item).then (
                // Log the fulfillment value
                function(val) {
                     console.log('Step 5: val: ' + val);
                     return(val);
                }
            )
            .catch (
                // Log the rejection reason
                function(reason) {
                    console.log('Step 6. Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
                    bPromiseRejected = true;
                    return("Error: " + reason);
                }
            );
        });
}

if (itemsToUpdate) {
    promisesUpdate = itemsToUpdate.map(function(item) {
        return tableRecord.update(item).then (
                // Log the fulfillment value
                function(val) {
                     console.log('Step 5: val: ' + val);
                     return(val);
                }
            )
            .catch (
                // Log the rejection reason
                function(reason) {
                    console.log('Step 6. Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
                    bPromiseRejected = true;
                    return("Error: " + reason);
                }
            );
        });
}

 promises = promisesInsert.concat(promisesUpdate);
 console.log('Promises: ' + util.inspect(promises, false, null));

  var result =  Promise.all(promises)
   .then(function(arrVals) { 
        //found an error in a promise
        console.log('Promise completed. Vals: ' + JSON.stringify(arrVals));
        var arrRet = [];
        for(var ind in arrVals) {
            var val = arrVals[ind];
            //if val is a string error, don't do anything
            console.log('Typeof Val: ' + typeof(val))
            if (typeof(val) === 'string') {
                console.log("Already Inserted. Skipping.Val: " + val);
                continue;
            } else {
                console.log("Item Inserted. Adding to Array. Val: " + val);
                arrRet.push(val)
            }
        }
        var result = {id:"Success", items: arrRet};
        console.log('All Records Inserted: ' + JSON.stringify(result)); 
        return res.end(JSON.stringify(result));

    }
 )
 .catch(
    function(reason) {
        var retVal =  { id: 'ERROR', reason: reason };
        console.error("Error: Promise Final.In catch. Reason: " + reason);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(retVal));
        console.log('After 400 submitted'); 
    }
 );
 return result;
 }

table.insert.use(insertMiddleware, table.operation);
table.insert(function (context) {
  return context.execute();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: In above code, I was missing delete function at this table level and it was executing project level delete function. after adding 
 
table.delete(function (context) {
  return context.execute();
});

and res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' }); in catch block of if (itemsToDelete) { it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you catch an exception in the middleware, you can try to use this line of code

```
res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
```

instead of `return("Error: " + reason);` to send the error to the client.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but it's not working even if I replaced each catch statement with res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' }); still it is sending me standard error message 
"error": "The item does not exist"
when I am trying to delete a record which does not exist.

Comment: Please note that I am very new to even basic nomenclature of easy table and related.

Comment: I am also trying to debug the Node.js backend easy table app using http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/app.js/debug/

but sometimes it hit sometimes it is not hitting the debugger. I am not sure my script code is even running or not

Comment: Even after commenting whole code in the table js file operation are still working through PostMan. 
It means this code block is not working if I hit the URL -
POST or DELETE http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/SYKHospital/id